# DFT and continuous Fourier transform gives different result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, fourier-analysis

I am working on the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{\sqrt{|k|}}{i(|k|-\omega)-\Gamma}$ with $\omega=100, \Gamma=1$. For continuous Fourier transform, I get the following result:

```
fx = InverseFourierTransform[Sqrt[Abs[k]]/(I (Abs[k] - 100) - 1), k,  x]
Plot[Abs[fx], {x, -200, 200}, PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

However, when I try the DFT, I get a completely different result:

```
f[k_] := Sqrt[Abs[k]]/(I (Abs[k] - 100) - 1);
sampling = Array[f, 10000, {0, 200}];
ListLinePlot[Abs[InverseFourier[sampling]], PlotRange -> {0, 1}, DataRange -> {0, 40 Pi}]
```

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with my code, sampling, wrong understanding of DFT? What are those peaks in continuous FT? Thanks for any help.

Comment: With `DFT`, the highest frequencies are _in the middle_. Notice also that `Fourier` and `InverseFourier` apply Fourier analysis on the _unit circle_ while `FourierTransform` and `InverseFourierTransform` perform Fourier analysis for the _real line_. I suggest to _read the manual_.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, As far as I know, a real function's Fourier transform is generally a complex function, and now I need to get the original function from its Fourier transform. BTW, this function is from quantum mechanics, so it may not be a real function.

Comment: It is not about real-valued or complex-valued functions: It is about the **domains** of functions. `Fourier` applies Fourier transform for piecewise-linear functions $f \colon S^1 \to \mathbb{C}$ on the unit circle $S^1$ while `FourierTransform` acts on functions on functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ on the real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `InverseFourierTransform` gives the result in terms of Fresnel integrals,

```
fx = InverseFourierTransform[Sqrt[Abs[k]]/(I (Abs[k] - 100) - 1), k, x]
```

> (1/Sqrt[2 [Pi]])(-((I Sqrt[2 [Pi]])/Sqrt[
>      Abs[x]]) + (2 + 200 I) Sqrt[-(100/10001) - I/
>       10001] [Pi] (-Cosh[(1 + 100 I) Abs[x]] + 
>        FresnelC[(Sqrt[20002/[Pi]] Sqrt[Abs[x]])/
>          Sqrt[-100 - I]] (Cosh[(1 + 100 I) Abs[x]] - 
>           I Sinh[(1 + 100 I) Abs[x]]) + 
>        FresnelS[(Sqrt[20002/[Pi]] Sqrt[Abs[x]])/
>          Sqrt[-100 - I]] (Cosh[(1 + 100 I) Abs[x]] + 
>           I Sinh[(1 + 100 I) Abs[x]])))

which is numerically very unstable to evaluate. 
A direct integration gives the result in terms of error functions,

```
Fx = 1/Sqrt[2π] Integrate[Sqrt[Abs[k]]/(I (Abs[k] - 100) - 1) E^(-I k x),
                          {k, -∞, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> -(1/(Sqrt[20002] Sqrt[-I x] Sqrt[I x]))
>    E^((-1 - 100 I) x) (I Sqrt[10001] E^((1 + 100 I) x) Sqrt[-I x] + 
>       I Sqrt[10001] E^((1 + 100 I) x) Sqrt[
>        I x] + (1 + 100 I) E^((2 + 200 I) x) Sqrt[(-100 - I) [Pi]]
>         Sqrt[-I x] Sqrt[I x] - (1 + 100 I) E^((2 + 200 I) x)
>         Sqrt[(-100 - I) [Pi]] Sqrt[-I x] Sqrt[I x]
>         Erf[(Sqrt[10001] Sqrt[-I x])/Sqrt[-100 - I]] + 
>       Sqrt[(1000100 - 10001 I) [Pi]] Sqrt[-I x] Sqrt[I x]
>         Erfc[Sqrt[-100 + I] Sqrt[I x]])

which is much easier to evaluate.

The results are the same apart from numerical artefacts for $\lvert x \rvert \gtrsim 16$:

```
Plot[{Abs[fx], Abs[Fx]}, {x, -20, 20},
     PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {InverseFunction, Integrate}]
```

[image]

The two curves evaluate to the same result if you use enough numerical precision.

It seems that the option `GenerateConditions -> False` is really the key to switching from Fresnel integrals to error functions, even though no conditions are generated without this option. Although the manual for `InverseFourierTransform` states that "Assumptions and other options to Integrate can also be given in InverseFourierTransform", the command `InverseFourierTransform[Sqrt[Abs[k]]/(I (Abs[k] - 100) - 1), k, x, GenerateConditions -> False]` still generates a result in terms of Fresnel integrals.

Comment: That answers my question, thanks a lot!